# footnote, hyperref, tabular

Tags: tables, hyperref, footnotes

I have many tables with footnotes inside and I need hyperref in my document.  Now, the problem is that footnote in my tables does not point to the notes at the end of the page. It points to the first page or doesn't print at all. How I do to correct that ? 
Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{colortbl,hhline} % au lieu de cline
\usepackage{footnote}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 0.95}}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, filecolor=blue, pagecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue}

\begin{document}
Titre
\newpage
\begin{savenotes}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{7cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{8cm}|}
\hline
un\footnote{note1}&deux\footnote{note2}\\
un\footnote{note3}&deux\footnote{note4}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Première table}
\end{table}%
\end{savenotes}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can solve the problem by these three steps:

1. Add `\usepackage{tablefootnote}` after your last `\hypersetup{...}` command, see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote.
2. Replace the `\footnote` commands in the table with `\tablefootnote` commands.
3. Remove the `\begin{savenotes}` and `\end{savenotes}` before/after the table.

Since version 1.1a `tablefootnote` also supports the optional argument of the `\footnote` command, for example `\tablefootnote[2]{text}`. Because version 1.1a has a bug, it is advisable to use a newer version (probably the most recent one).

Comment: `tablefootnote` package does not address the optional argument of `\footnote` command: `\tablefootnote[2]{text}`

Comment: @Vafa: That was the case for older versions indeed. The recent version(s) support the optional argument.