# Footnote in tabularx doesn't work (with hyperref)

Tags: tables, hyperref, footnotes, tabularx

Here is the min file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}[1999/01/07] % v2.07
\usepackage{hyperref}% 2012/10/15 v6.83k
\listfiles
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c}
text\footnote{footnote test} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

With the above codes, the output pdf file doesn't present "footnote test" in table footnote area.

Comment: There are many ways around this: [Footnotes `tabularx`-environment LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51454/5764); [footnote, hyperref, tabular](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78911/5764)...

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 6):

The command `\footnote` is divided into `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}[1999/01/07] % v2.07
\usepackage{hyperref}% 2012/10/15 v6.83k
\listfiles
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c}
text\footnote{footnote test} 
and text\footnotemark %1
and text\footnotemark %2
\\
\end{tabularx}
\footnotetext{second} %1
\end{minipage}
\footnotetext{third} %2

\end{document}
```

Please observe different behaviour of footnotes marked `%1` and `%2`, respectively.

[image]